# A way to intercept all strings in response object and perform some operation before sending it to the server

Tags: spring-boot, jackson2

I am using a Spring boot based stack. Its an old code base. What I wanted to do was to perform an operation on a type of object before sending it to the client as a response. For example, lets say, I have a `Person` class defined as (pseudo code):
`class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)`. Now when sending it as a response to the server, I want to perform a `trim` operation on all members of type `String`. Is there a way to do this? What I have done till now is created a `MappingJackson2HttpConverter` instance and an `ObjectMapper` which I am linking to the instance of `MappingJackson2HttpConverter`. This converter is added to the list of `HttpMessageConverters` in a class marked `@COnfiguration` and extending`WebMvcConfirurerAdapter`. So there are two things over here:

- Is this the correct approach?

  - If so, how do I implement `ObjectMapper`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ResponseBodyAdvice<T>` provided by Spring. It Allows customizing the response after the execution of an `@ResponseBody` or a `ResponseEntity` controller method but before the body is written with an `HttpMessageConverter`.

Link : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html

Comment: Tried this but I only want the beans of my application to be intercepted. Not all the beans